# How to access Page views from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, windows

I want to access a View which is defined in a Page class's child, called MyPage, from the Application class's child, called App.

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Here I want to access a view in MyPage class
            }
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to access it from App.cs?

Comment: Because I need to change the Text value of the TexBox view in the OnLaunched() method, which is available for override in the App class (because it inherits Application class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way!

We can grab the Page instance by (MyPage)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content

Just create a public method in the MyPage class, and call it from the App class in the OnLaunched() method by:

```
Frame rootFrame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
MyPage myPage = (MyPage)rootFrame.Content;
if (myPage != null)
{
    myPage.MyMethod(...);
}
```